# Get next or previous post using the Tumblr API

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, tumblr

I've written a JS application that uses the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts).

- A listing page makes a request to the API that returns 20 or so results.
- A post page request specifies an ID and is returned a single post.

For the post page, I want to get some information about the next chronological post (Like you can do with the Theme builder using `{PreviousPost}` or `{NextPost}`).

Ideally I'd get the whole next post, however the ID would be sufficient as I can make a second call to get the information I need to display. (I.e. The post title to display as a link).

As far as I'm aware there's nothing in the API that allows me to access this information. Does anybody know a way to retrieve this info without my absolute worst case scenario? (getting ALL the posts and looping through to see which posts surround the one in question)

Comment: Sadly, I think you worst case scenario is the only way to work around this. I wish I had better news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue in 2 ways:

1. I created an app-wide variable that is used to store a collection of all the posts. Each time I load more posts I add them to this collection and can access its contents at any time. If I load a post page where the post isn't yet in the global collection, or if it's the last post in the current collection (ie. next post is not available), I ask the server for more posts so I can access the next post.
2. I reverted to using the Tumblr theme builder and used the same approach that @Tony touched on in his answer. I printed the link to the next and previous posts, and parsed them with JS to obtain the post ID. I then queried the API to return the details of the next and previous posts (separate calls). I then injected this info into my markup.

Both solutions require multiple requests and cannot be done as default behaviour with Tumblr at this time. The 2nd solution is the one that made it to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. What I simply did was putting {PreviousPost} into the DOM, like `<span class="nextPost-ID">{PreviousPost}</span>`, and then retrieved the ID with javascript. After that I can call the API with the ID to retrieve other information.